# How can I combine these regular expressions

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to combine these three regular expressions, but I dont know if its possible, because the result is different.

What I really want is to delete all space before and after of all strings in an array or object. Also, I need to delete two or more spaces between a string.

Actually the code does the necessary to get expected result, but I want to shorten the code.

```js
let persona = {
    name: 'Tomas  Torres Caleron',
    edad: 26
  },
  casa = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: 'las condes '
  },
  persona1 = {
    name: 'Catalina  Zaror  ""      Letelier',
    edad: 24
  },
  casa1 = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: ' las condes '
  },
  empleado1 = {
    persona: persona,
    casa: casa
  },
  empleado2 = {
    persona: persona1,
    casa: casa1
  },
  empleados = [empleado1, empleado2];




console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(empleados).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"').replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, ' ').replace(/\\"/g, '')));
```

This is the expected result:

```js
{
  "empleados": [{
      "persona": {
        "name": "Tomas Torres Caleron",
        "edad": 26
      },
      "casa": {
        "direccion": "aa",
        "comuna": "las condes"
      }
    },
    {
      "persona": {
        "name": "Catalina Zaror Letelier",
        "edad": 24
      },
      "casa": {
        "direccion": "aa",
        "comuna": "las condes"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

```
JSON.stringify({empleados})
```

```js
let persona = {
    name: 'Tomas  Torres Caleron',
    edad: 26
  },
  casa = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: 'las condes '
  },
  persona1 = {
    name: 'Catalina  Zaror  ""      Letelier',
    edad: 24
  },
  casa1 = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: ' las condes '
  },
  empleado1 = {
    persona: persona,
    casa: casa
  },
  empleado2 = {
    persona: persona1,
    casa: casa1
  },
  empleados = [empleado1, empleado2];




console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({empleados}).replace(/"\s+|\s+"/g, '"').replace(/[ ]{2,}/g, ' ').replace(/\\"/g, '')));
```

Using `JSON.stringify()`'s `replacer` method

> JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])

**Regex:** https://regex101.com/r/iB4QBl/1

```js
let persona = {
    name: 'Tomas  Torres Caleron',
    edad: 26
  },
  casa = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: 'las condes '
  },
  persona1 = {
    name: 'Catalina  Zaror  ""      Letelier',
    edad: 24
  },
  casa1 = {
    direccion: ' aa',
    comuna: ' las condes '
  },
  empleado1 = {
    persona: persona,
    casa: casa
  },
  empleado2 = {
    persona: persona1,
    casa: casa1
  },
  empleados = [empleado1, empleado2];




console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify({empleados}, (key, value) => {
  if (typeof value === 'string') {
    return value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$|\"|(\s?\"+\s?|\s+)(?=\s)/g, '')
  }
  return value;
})))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need combine the regular expressions, because I believe that to have many replace in a sentence is not very effective.  
My code can do the necessary trims, but I don't know how combine de regular expressions.
Anyway, I would like to know if your code is more efficient than mine.